# What is the difference between photo and thumbnail?

Tags: html, css, image, thumbnails, photo

I am learning web development. Sometimes I come across certain images in dual format. In one folder they are given as photo and in another folder they are given as thumbnail. Also in both the folders they are in .jpg format. The only difference I found is that the thumbnail images are smaller in dimension than their photo counterparts.

So is there any real purpose of using thumbnail and photo of the same image separately when I can easily modify dimensions using `width` and `height` attribute in `<img>` tag of HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a page where you show a *lot* of photos (for example a gallery page) it's better to use small file sizes for faster loading. So in this case you would use the thumbnails, whereas when you link those to the large images on single pages (i.e. one photo per page, or the overlays in lightboxes), you would use the large size to get better quality.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of using separate much smaller files as thumbnails is mainly loading speed of the page and saving bandwidth - you don't need to wait until the whole image is downloaded for the browser to render it's thumbnail. It makes a big difference with bigger images (like HD wallpapers for example), where images could easily be over 1MB in size. If you have gallery of thumbnails that would take a while to load, even on a very fast connection, instead you use thumbnails which are generally under 100kB (in most cases much smaller).
This also saves you bandwidth, because you only download the images the user needs, not all of them.
This comes from my experience building web galleries and portfolios.